# How to get the value instead of order_id with get_post_meta()

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've had the following code to add a custom order field in the woocommerce checkout:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
   $fields['billing']['billing_reason_for_purchase'] = array(
       'label' => __('Reason for purchase', 'woocommerce'),
       'placeholder' => _x('Reason for purchase', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
       'required' => false,
       'type' => 'select',
       'class' => array('form-row-first'),
       'options' => array(
           'option_1' => __('Personal', 'woocommerce'),
           'option_2' => __('Academic', 'woocommerce'),
           'option_3' => __('Small Business', 'woocommerce'),
           'option_4' => __('Large Organization', 'woocommerce')
       )
   );
   return $fields;
}
```

Then, followed by the below code to update the order meta with field value

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta($order_id) {
    if(!empty($_POST['billing_reason_for_purchase'])) {
        update_post_meta($order_id,'Reason for purchase',sanitize_text_field($_POST['billing_reason_for_purchase']));
    }
}
```

Next, display the field on the order edit page:

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta',10,1);
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    //echo '<p><strong>'.__('Reason for purchase').':<strong>'.get_post_meta($order->id, 'Reason for purchase',true).'</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Reason for purchase').':<strong>'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Reason for purchase',true).'</p>';
}
```

The problem I'm having is if I created a dummy order with choosing "academic" as the reason for purchase, I'd get "option_2" instead of "academic" in the order edit page.

Please help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the value of the selected option (and so of `$_POST['billing_reason_for_purchase']`) is actually the key of the array (in your example `option_2`) and not the text related. In fact this is the option tag created:

```
<option value="option_2">Academic</option>
```

You're saving only the key of your array.

So you need to retrieve the array of options even on the `my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta` function to get the proper text.

You could copy the array in each function (but is not convenient to duplicate code), or put it in a global variable to be able to access it from anywhere (but then something else could change it), so instead you can use a function that returns the array:

```
function reasons_for_purchase () {
    return array(
       'option_1' => __('Personal', 'woocommerce'),
       'option_2' => __('Academic', 'woocommerce'),
       'option_3' => __('Small Business', 'woocommerce'),
       'option_4' => __('Large Organization', 'woocommerce')
   );
}
```

And then use it where you need it:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields');
function custom_override_checkout_fields($fields) {
   $fields['billing']['billing_reason_for_purchase'] = array(
       'label' => __('Reason for purchase', 'woocommerce'),
       'placeholder' => _x('Reason for purchase', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
       'required' => false,
       'type' => 'select',
       'class' => array('form-row-first'),
       'options' => reasons_for_purchase()
   );
   return $fields;
}

add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address','my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta',10,1);
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    $reasons = reasons_for_purchase();
    $reason  = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Reason for purchase', true);
    if( isset($reasons[$reason]) )
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('Reason for purchase').':</strong> '. $reasons[$reason] .'</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in regards to d79's provided brilliant solution, it worked formed after a few tweaks to the syntax. It may have not worked me initially possibly because of outdated syntax, so I'll try list out the changes that I've made and that worked for me.

1). Updating the options array syntax:

```
'option_1' => __('Personal', 'woocommerce'),
```

to

```
'option_1' => 'Personal',
```

2). Updating the get_post_meta syntax:

```
get_post_meta($order->id,
```

to

```
get_post_meta($order->get_id(),
```

3). Changing the second variable in the get_post_meta, since for me intially it didn't output the array key of the selected option. So basically what worked, was using the field name as the second variable with a "_" symbol in front. As as an eg. I'm adding the whole code line for the variable "$reason" which illustrates the change.

```
$reason  = get_post_meta($order->id, 'Reason for purchase', true);
```

to

```
$reason  = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_billing_reason_for_purchase', true);
```